# Why does including cxf-rt-rs-client break jersey-media-json-processing

Tags: java, maven, cxf, dependency-management, jersey-client

If I create a Java (Maven) project (called com.example.lib) with the following App class

```
package com.example.lib;

import javax.json.JsonObject;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class App 
{

    public String getJson(String url) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = client.target( url )
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .get();
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return response.readEntity( JsonObject.class ).toString();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println(new App().getJson(args[0]));
    }
}
```

and the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I can call the getJson method with "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:%22Drosophila%22%20and%20body:%22RNA%22&fl=id,abstract&wt=json&indent=on" (or any http endpoint that returns JSON) and everything works as expected.

This behaviour can be demonstrated as follows

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/my-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-run.jar "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:%22Drosophila%22%20and%20body:%22RNA%22&fl=id,abstract&wt=json&indent=on"
```

If I add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and do nothing else then I get the following error when making the call

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setupOutInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:847)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.createMessage(AbstractClient.java:924)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.finalizeMessage(WebClient.java:1109)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1082)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:883)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:854)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:417)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1609)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1604)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.get(WebClient.java:1524)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.InvocationBuilderImpl.get(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:80)
    at com.example.lib.App.getJson(App.java:21)
    at com.example.lib.App.main(App.java:30)
```

Why does this happen?

How should I resolve this?

There's a project demonstrating this at https://github.com/HughPowell/my-lib.

Note: This is a simplified case of what is actually happening.  I'm depending on two libraries that each themselves, somewhere down the dependency chain, respectively depend on each of these dependencies.

Comment: How to use "my-lib" to reproduce the problem? mvn clean install works without any error.

Comment: @ColmOhEigeartaigh Despite being called my-lib it can also be run as a stand alone jar like so `java -jar target/my-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-run.jar "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:%22Drosophila%22%20and%20body:%22RNA%22&fl=id,abstract&wt=json&indent=on"` (assuming you're in the root of the project).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following transformer to your maven shade plugin:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
</transformer>
```

See here for an explanation:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/bundling-cxf-into-single-jar-with-maven-shade-plugin.html

Also note your client code will fail - you need to add:

.header("Content-type", "application/json")

for the example URL you gave above.